# In WPF, how can I add a border to a control in code behind?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

In my XAML I want to dynamically generate a ListBox with the following:

```
<ListBox Name="MainListBox">
  <Border Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemRoundedBorder}">
     <ListBoxItem >
        <TextBlock>
          Some Text Here
        </TextBlock>
     </ListBoxItem>
   </Border>

  <Border Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemRoundedBorder}">
     <ListBoxItem >
        <TextBlock>
          Some Text Here
        </TextBlock>
     </ListBoxItem>
   </Border>

  <Border Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemRoundedBorder}">
     <ListBoxItem >
        <TextBlock>
          Some Text Here
        </TextBlock>
     </ListBoxItem>
   </Border>
</ListBox>
```

I want to add items to this listbox via code behind.  How can I add the item and the border via code behind.  I can add the list box items easy enough but can't seem to figure out the border:

```
 For Each s As String in MyArray
   Dim lbi as New ListBoxItem()
   Dim tb as New TextBlock()
   tb.Text = s
   lbi.content = tb
   MainListBox.Items.Add(lbi)
 Next
```

Edit:  To clear up any confusion I want a border around each of the ListBox Items.  I've updated the XAML - effectively I want to render that XAML dynamically, or equivalent, via code behind.  I already have the border style defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked in to Templating the [ListBoxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750821.aspx)

Use this to get the border effect you're looking for

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemRoundedBorder" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Border 
          Name="Border"
          Padding="2"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Style="{DynamicResource RoundedBorder}">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then on your listbox use

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemRoundedBorder}" />
```

Although, based on your question, I can't exactly see what design your looking for.  Are you looking for a List with a border around it or a list with a border around each item?

Comment: I'm looking for a list with a border around each item, I updated the question to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Then I would go with the template method describe in my answer.  This way, you don't have to worry about appending a border element via code.

Comment: ok, but there are other list items, in other list boxes in the same user control, that I do not want to apply this border to, how can I selectively apply this template?

Comment: So in order to accomidate this you can use the ListView.ItemContainerStyle key.  Note.  I changed your keynames to ListBoxItemRoundedBorder and RoundedBorder, since the ListBoxItemRoundedBorder wasn't a great name for a Border style.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand. If you want one `Border`, why not just stick it on the *outside* of the `ListBox`? I'll assume you want one `Border` *per `ListBoxItem`*. In that case, just modify the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </Border>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"I want to add items to this listbox via code behind."*

I have just built a page that loads controls to the page dynamically (based on a collection).

So to answer the the question... you must apply the settings (like what is done with the templating in xaml) in your code.  Here is an example in C#: (in vb the first line would start with Dim listBoxStyle as Style...)

```
Style listBoxStyle = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(ListBox));
listBoxStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBox.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0,0,0,0)));
ListBox rdoList = new ListBox();
rdoList.Resources.Add(typeof(ListBox), listBoxStyle);
```

Notice the thickness(). I have mine set to no border as it defaults to having a border.  You can do this with your textboxes and just add the thickness like (1,1,1,1).

Don't know how your calling your dynamic controls from code but you may want to [view this post for an easy way to access dynamic wpf controls by name value from code](http://brettspencer.name/_brettspencer/post/2011/03/11/WPF-Dynamic-Controls.aspx).